# how to create virtualbox vmdk file from zip

Tags: virtualbox

I have a `.zip` file I'd like to turn into a `.vmdk` file.

I've tried the command:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename usb.vmdk -rawdisk "c:\Contents.zip"
```

but I receive error:

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Detected size of raw disk 'c:\Contents.zip' is 6014441999, an invalid value
VBoxManage.exe: error: The raw disk vmdk file was not created
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `createrawvmdk` in this manner.  `createrawvmdk` is for using real, physical hard disks instead of virtual drives in a virtual machine.  It is not used for mounting a file is a disk.

The error most likely stems from the fact that `createrawvmdk` is trying to get the size of a physical disk, but is just reading what is essentially random data from the ZIP file.  It seems to be aware 6 petabytes isnt correct.

For example, the correct way to use `createrawvmdk` is this:  I have two SSDs in my machine, one has Windows and one has Linux.  I can boot off either hard drive.  However, I created a VM in Windows, and used the `createrawvmdk` to allow me to boot my real, physical Linux drive in a a VM in Windows.

Read more about `createrawvmdk` [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html).

It looks like you are trying to use a ZIP file as a disk.  I dont know if that is possible.  However, I would doubt it, as the ZIP would have to be completely decompressed to be read and completely recompressed when done.  That is very resource intensive and depending on the size, could take a *very* long time.  Using a ZIP file in this manner doesnt make much sense.

Perhaps your ZIP file contains a disk image?  If so, you would need to extract it.  VirtualBox is compatible with many disk image types.  Therefore if the image was supported, you could then mount it as a drive.